# Is it illegal to use my personal cell phone for work related matters?

Tags: communication, company-policy, work-time

I'm a restaurant manager and contact crew members via text sometimes. Someone told me that it's illegal, and I should only use the company land line and call them. 
Our company has not had a policy other than employees are not to use their cell phones while working.

Comment: Not a chance that it's illegal, at all.  It might be against your company's policy, but I really doubt it.

Comment: thanks, I didn't think so. We don't have a policy against it.

Comment: [legal advice](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/what-is-asking-for-legal-advice) is explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 3):

> Company policy does not equal law.

That's the bottom line.

Illegal means that it is against the law.

Against company policy means you might be reprimanded by your HR, fired and possibly in worse extreme case taken to court.

If you need to communicate with your staff as part of your job - then you should raise this request to your management to provide you with a mobile that is owned and controlled by the company.

This way, both you and your employer are covered.  You are not using personal devices to communicate what could be confidential information; and the company is in control because they manage the device that you are using and can audit it at will.

Answer (score 1):

If you work in a heavily regulated environment, this may be against the law.  For example, in some countries finance workers have to record all their calls and all their texts are monitored to ensure they aren't committing fraud.  If they use their personal phones, they could be breaking the law.

I don't know where you live, but I don't think restaurant managers are *that* heavily regulated!

If you often need to text / call your employees, I would suggest speaking to your manager, and finding out what the policy is.

They may give you a company phone - for use only in relation with company business.  Or they may reimburse you for calls and texts you send from your personal account.

Comment: Many people have a phone plan where they pay for x minutes of calls and y text messages and are nowhere near using that amount for private use, so making some extra calls or sending some extra text messages doesn't cost them anything.